# How to deploy contract with bytecode from etherscan?

Tags: contract-deployment, bytecode, opcode

For example, I want to deploy a contract to my local testnet. But I only have its opcode from etherscan. How to deploy the contract with just those runtime bytecode?

Answer (score 0):

You will also need ABI, not just bytecode. Look at the next article, it will give you good starting point: https://medium.com/@prashantprabhakarsingh/deploying-contract-using-bytecode-myetherwallet-and-remix-10f643a82d40

Comment: You do not need the ABI to deploy a contract. It is needed if you want to interact with the contract.

Comment: How can you set constructor parameters if you don't have ABI?

Comment: You are correct! If the constructor need parameters you only need the constructor ABI.

Comment: how can I construct ABI? I know the parameters eg. (address to, address from, unit amount)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to deploy exactly the same contract and don't need the ABI, you can simply copy the transaction data of the deployment transaction. And then, depending on what kind of provider you have, it would look something like this.

```js
  const sendTx = async () => {
    const data = '0x....'; // opcode here
    const params = [
      {
        from: account,
        data: data,
      },
      'latest',
    ];
    await provider.send('eth_sendTransaction', params)
  }
```

If you can connect to it via an rpc endpoint and add that to MetaMask, you can go here: https://lovethewired.github.io/abi-playground
and paste in the deployment data and click on 'send'.

Answer (score 0):

When someone needs to use the mainnet contracts and also the data in their local networks, the most convenient way is - the **forking**. We use [hardhat/mainnet-forking](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks#mainnet-forking).
Due to the deterministic storage access in EVM, the forking works fast and seamlessly:

- when you call a method of a contract address that is not yet in the local chain, the contract will be downloaded under the hood with `getCode`.
- when during the method execution a storage slot is accessed, which is not yet in the local chain, the data will be automatically fetched with `getStorageAt`.

Sometimes if you want to call a method that is for example with `onlyOwner` modifier, with hardhat you have a lot of development methods:

- you can execute transactions with any EOA address as the sender
- you can modify the contract's storage to set your own EOA address for the `owner` state variable

You may need the verified contracts from Etherscan when you need to **modify** the source code of a contract and redeploy it to the local network. We use [0xweb](https://0xweb.org) for this purpose

```bash
0xweb i 0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48 --name USDC --chain eth
```

This downloads the ABI and the source code from Etherscan, after that you modify the source code you find in `./0xweb/eth/USDC/**.sol`

```bash
0xweb deploy USDC --deployer Foo --chain hardhat
```